# Pandas: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply an expanding function to a pandas dataframe by group, but first filtering out all zeroes as well as the last value of each group. The code below does exactly what I need, but is a bit too slow:

```
df.update(df.loc[~df.index.isin(df.groupby('group')['value'].tail(1).index)&
            (df['value']!= 0)].iloc[::-1].groupby('group')[
            'value'].expanding().min().reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

I found a faster way doing this using below code:

```
df.update(df.iloc[::-1].groupby('group')[
            'value'].expanding().min().reset_index(level=0, drop=True), 
             filter_func = lambda x: (x!=0)&(x[-1]==False))
```

However, with the dataset I am currently working on, I receive a warning ("C:...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:22: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.").

Strangely enough, I don't get an error using small dummy datasets such as this:

```
data = {'group':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 
                'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
                 'value':[3, 0, 8, 7, 0, -1, 0, 9, -2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 1]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

  group  value
0   A      3
1   A      0
2   A      8
3   A      7
4   A      0
5   B     -1
6   B      0
7   B      9
8   B     -2
9   B      0
10  B      0
11  C      2
12  C      0
13  C      5
14  C      0
15  C      1
```

Grateful if someone can help me understand why this error is coming up and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your fist code should be improved by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for better performance, second code not working for me:

```
m = df.duplicated('group', keep='last') & (df['value']!= 0)
s = df[m].iloc[::-1].groupby('group')['value'].expanding().min().reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df.update(s)
#alternative, not sure if faster
#df['value'] = s.reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
print (df)
   group  value
0      A    3.0
1      A    0.0
2      A    7.0
3      A    7.0
4      A    0.0
5      B   -2.0
6      B    0.0
7      B   -2.0
8      B   -2.0
9      B    0.0
10     B    0.0
11     C    2.0
12     C    0.0
13     C    5.0
14     C    0.0
15     C    1.0
```